# Add field to json with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to add a new json field conditionally looking for others fields values using python, like that:

```
{
   "id":"x2342345ap",
   "quantity":1,
   "timestamp":"2022-09-26",
   "details":[
      {
         "name":"robert",
         "color":"red", 
         "age": 25         
      }
   ]
}
```

And then looking into the details.field (name, color, age) create a new field. Like, if the name is different of James, add 'ugly name' to an array for this new field and the same for the color:

```
{
   "id":"x2342345ap",
   "quantity":1,
   "timestamp":"2022-09-26",
   "problems": ['ugly name', 'ugly color']
   "details":[
      {
         "name":"robert",
         "color":"red", 
         "age": 25         
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: JSON is really irrelevant here, as is pandas.  This is just ordinary Python code.  What have you tried?

Comment: What should the field be if the name is `James` and the colour is the "right" one?

Comment: The color would be different of yellow to add 'ugly color' and the name if is different of james add 'ugly name' for the new array field (problems)

Comment: @TimRoberts I've tried but not with sucess :/

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  You need to show us what you've done, point out what isn't working, and then we can help direct you.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat JSON similarly to how you interact with native dictionaries and lists. For example, I'll start with a string, convert to JSON, and then add a note to the list of problems:

```
import json
jsonstring = """
{
   "id":"x2342345ap",
   "quantity":1,
   "timestamp":"2022-09-26",
   "details":[
      {
         "name":"robert",
         "color":"red", 
         "age": 25         
      }
   ]
}
"""
myjson = json.loads(jsonstring)

if myjson["details"][0]["name"] == "robert":
  if "problems" not in myjson:
    myjson["problems"] = ["good name!"]
  else:
    myjson["problems"].append("good name!")
```